# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent event on select?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is there a way to add an event on select/get with eloquent ?

I only see these methods :

```
public function getObservableEvents()
    {
        return array_merge(
            array(
                'creating', 'created', 'updating', 'updated',
                'deleting', 'deleted', 'saving', 'saved',
                'restoring', 'restored',
            ),
            $this->observables
        );
    }
```

I want to be able to change values returned by a model

I have this model :

```
class Fee extends Eloquent {
        protected $table = 'fees';
        protected $fillable = array('occ_paxs_id',
                                    'description',
                                    'amount',
                                    'other',
                                    'hstgst',
                                    'pst',);
    }

$fee = Fee::find($id); // here I want to be able to add a markup on the property amount
```

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent supports custom accessors and mutators. From the vague description in your question, these will likely do what you need.

```
class Fee extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'occ_paxs_id',
        'description',
        'amount',
        'other',
        'hstgst',
        'pst',
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'formatted_amount',
    ];


    /**
     * Override the default attribute accessor.
     */
    public function getAmountAttribute($value)
    {
        return "This is the amount - {$value}";
    }

    /**
     * Or define a custom attribute accessor.
     */
    public function getFormattedAmountAttribute()
    {
        return "This is my formatted amount - {$this->amount}";
    }
}


$fee = Fee::find($id);

echo $fee->amount;  // This is the amount - 0.00
echo $fee->formatted_amount; // This is my formatted amount - 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have Observers @ ORM (e.g. Fee) but it only tracks the regular operations over a single ORM instance: created, creating, updated, updating, deleted, deleting and a couple more I believe.

You can use Mutator and Accessor like this to alter data before insertion and after retrieving data:

```
class Fee extends Eloquent {
        protected $table = 'fees';
        protected $fillable = array('occ_paxs_id',
                                    'description',
                                    'amount',
                                    'other',
                                    'hstgst',
                                    'pst',);
        //Mutator = before it inserts into the database, it converts $value to a lower case string
        public function setAmountAttribute($value) {
             $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
        }

        //Accessor - after it retrieves data from the database, it places the capital letter in UpperCase (ucfirst).
        public function getAmountAttribute($value) {
              return ucfirst($value);
        }
}
```

By creating a function that starts with `get` and ends with `Attribute`, laravel finds the attribute related based on the name. You can also get non-existant attributes and apply logic to it, if needed (for example, getting a fullName of a person in the example below, meaning a variable called fullName will be returned in your ORM result with it's content):

```
public function getFullNameAttribute() {
    return $this->attributes['first_name'] " . " $this->attributes['last_name'];
}
```

> https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 0):

There is a `retrieved` event that was added in Laravel 5.5.

> *The `retrieved` event will fire when an existing model is retrieved from the database.*

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events